# Cannot share screen as a co-host with Zoom Meeting on Linux

Tags: linux, screen-sharing, zoom-meeting

I'm using Zoom Meeting for Linux.

**Despite being co-host**, I cannot do screen **sharing**. When I click on the Share icon, a message "Host disabled participant screen sharing" is displayed. Other co-hosts, using Windows or MacOS, can share. (Even I, with Zoom for Android, I'm allowed to share.)

Advancing Sharing Options window shows the following entries (options are read only):

- How many participants can share at the same time?

  ```
  [X] One participant can share at a time
  [ ] Multiple participant can share similtaneously (dual monitor recommended)
  ```
- Who can share?

  ```
  [X] Only Host
  [ ] All Participants
  ```
- Who can start sharing when someone else is sharing?

  ```
  [X] Only Host
  [ ] All Participants
  ```

Here is the environnement:

- Zoom 5.2.458699.0906 (latest build on Linux)
- Linux Slackware x86_64 14.2

Advancing Sharing Options Screenshot:

[image: Advanced Sharing Options]

---

**Update.**
The issue doesn't occur with all zoom accounts hosting a billable room. One let me do a screen sharing as a co-host while the other won't.